# Pushing multiple images to multiple Rows

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to push multiple images for multiple rows. It is working for the first row. But for the consequent rows the images inserted inside first array are showing.
````React
const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

```
  const imageHandler = (e) => {
    const multiple = e.target.files
    for(let i = 0; i < multiple.length; i++) {
      images.push(multiple[i])
    }
    setImages([images])
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.clear();
    images.length && console.log(images)
  },[images])



images.map((user, index) => (
                    <tr key={index}>
                      <td><input type="file" onChange={imageHandler} required multiple /></td>
                    </tr>
                  ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your comment, if I understand you correctly.
You can try this:

```
const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

const imageHandler = (e) => {
    const multiple = e.target.files;
    setImages(prev => {
        return [...prev, multiple]
    })
}

return (
    <>
        {
            images.map((imageArr, index) => {
                return (
                    <tr key={index}>
                        {
                            (imageArr || []).map((item, indexChild) => {
                                return (
                                    <td key={indexChild}>
                                        <input type="file" onChange={imageHandler} required multiple />
                                    </td>
                                )
                            })
                        }
                    </tr>
                )
            })
        }
    </>
)
```

Comment: I have multiple rows. It works for the first row. But as soon as I insert images in the second row, it's showing in the same array. I want to push multiple images for one row and the different multiple images for the other rows.

Comment: Updated my answer, hope it can help @RiteshSrivastava